# How can I make an API after compiling and running my pipeline on Kubeflow?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I built a pipeline which takes an image and returns a number of  persons. I want to make an API which takes an image and returns a JSON file with count using Kubeflow.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you can deploy a model for inference from a pipeline:

- You can use Kubeflow components like [KFServing](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/serving/kfserving/) and the [KFServing Deployer](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/components/kubeflow/kfserving) component for Kubeflow Pipelines
- If you are using a cloud provider, they may have services you can use for inference. For example, there is a component that [deploys trained models to Google Cloud AI Platform](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/components/gcp/ml_engine/deploy)
- Or, you could build a custom solution